# Day and night in heaven?

Tags: tafseer

Allah says in Surah Maryam:

> They will not hear therein any ill speech - only [greetings of] peace - and they will have their provision therein, **morning and afternoon**.

Does this ayah mean there is day and night in heaven?

Answer (score 1):

No. Most Tafsirs from scholars say it means 'equivalence' of those time measurements, not literal day/night in Paradise. Among the Tafsirs on this portion of the ayah (19:62):

- "This means, in what is similar to mornings and evenings. This does not mean that there is a night and a day (in Paradise), but they will be living in times that alternate. They will know its lighted times from its lights and illumination" [Tafsîr Ibn Kathir].
- "(for morn and evening) in the measure of the morning and evening of this worldly life" [Tanwîr al-Miqbâs min Tafsîr Ibn ‘Abbâs]
- "And therein they will have their provision morning and evening, in other words, according to the [equivalent] measure of these two in the [life of this] world, since there is no day or night in Paradise, only everlasting light and illumination" [Tafsîr Al-Jalalayn].

So there may be different time periods with varying levels of light (some brighter than other times) but there'll be no darkness/'night'. Darkness will just be a setting in Hell.

Comment: Barakallahu fiki for this useful answer. Can I ask you, what website or app are you using which allows you to consult multiple tafasir of one verse at once?

Comment: https://quranx.com/

Comment: Jazakallahu khairan